# Binary Subtraction - Python

Tags: python, binary

I want to make a binary calculator and I have a problem with the subtraction part. Here is my code (I have tried to adapt one for sum that I've found on this website).

```python
    maxlen = max(len(s1), len(s2))

    s1 = s1.zfill(maxlen)
    s2 = s2.zfill(maxlen)

    result  = ''
    carry   = 0

    i = maxlen - 1
    while(i >= 0):
        s = int(s1[i]) - int(s2[i])
        if s <= 0:
            if carry == 0 and s != 0:
                carry = 1
                result = result + "1"
            else:
                result = result + "0"
        else:
            if carry == 1:
                result = result + "0"
                carry = 0   
            else:
                result = result + "1" 
        i = i - 1


    if carry>0:
        result = result + "1"

    return result[::-1]
```

The program works fine with some binaries subtraction but it fails with others.
Can someone please help me because I can't find  the mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Delete all your existing code and write `def SubtractionBinary(s1, s2): return bin(int(s1, 2) - int(s2, 2))[2:]`

Comment: Please describe the idea of your approach. Does it make sense?

Comment: @user3856011 - @kindall is pointing out that you can use `int(s, 2)` to convert a binary string `s` to a Python integer, use built-in subtraction, then call `bin()` on the result to convert back to a binary string.

Comment: Your code is based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26953824/2572431) for binary sum, right?

Comment: @augurar: You misunderstood my question. I wanted user2328079 to rethink his approach, because I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Your code is wrong for the case when `s1[i] == s2[i]` and `carry == 1`.

**Longer answer:** You should restructure your code to have three separate cases for `s==-1`, `s==0`, and `s==1`, and then branch on the value of `carry` within each case:

```
if s == -1:  # 0-1
    if carry == 0:
        ...
    else:
        ...
elif s == 0:  # 1-1 or 0-0
    if carry == 0:
        ...
    else:
        ...
else:  # 1-0
    if carry == 0:
         ...
    else:
        ...
```

This way you have a separate block for each possibility, so there is no chance of overlooking a case like you did on your first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the answer below it helps.

```
def binarySubstration(str1,str2):
if len(str1) == 0:
    return
if len(str2) == 0:
    return 

str1,str2 = normaliseString(str1,str2)
startIdx = 0
endIdx = len(str1) - 1
carry = [0] * len(str1)
result = ''


while endIdx >= startIdx:
    x = int(str1[endIdx])
    y = int(str2[endIdx])
    sub = (carry[endIdx] + x) - y

    if sub == -1:
        result += '1'
        carry[endIdx-1] = -1

    elif sub == 1:
        result += '1'
    elif sub == 0:
        result += '0'
    else:
        raise Exception('Error')

    endIdx -= 1
   
return result[::-1]
```

normalising the strings

```
def normaliseString(str1,str2):
    diff = abs((len(str1) - len(str2)))
    if diff != 0:
        if len(str1) < len(str2):
            str1 = ('0' * diff) + str1
            
        else:
            str2 = ('0' * diff) + str2
           
    return [str1,str2]
```